# Use ANTLR4 to get a method's annotations

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a short program that scans a Java source file and finds all the methods in it using `ANTLR4`. For each method, I'd like to check whether it is a test method or not, and I want to do so by checking if the method has the `@Test` annotation.

How can I get a list of annotations for each method I'm visiting? Here's my source code so far:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(sourceFile, "UTF-8"));
    parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();

    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    MyListener listener = new MyListener(printToFile);
    walker.walk(listener, tree);
}

public static class MyListener extends JavaBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterMethodDeclaration(JavaParser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
        // Mark the method's boundaries and extract the method text
        int begin_offset = ctx.start.getStartIndex();
        int end_offset = ctx.stop.getStopIndex();
        Interval interval = new Interval(begin_offset, end_offset);
        String methodText = ctx.start.getInputStream().getText(interval);

        // Get the list of annotations - how?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use [this Java grammar for antlr](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4). I'm working on memory since don't have the tools to test what I'm doing at hand. Reading the grammar you can learn quickly that:

- Annotations correspond to the rule annotation (wow) so you'll find them in an AnnotationContext in the generated tree.
- Annotations are linked to a member of a class (for example a method) in the classBodyDeclaration rule (modifier can be a classOrInterfaceModifier, which can be an annotation)

In this case we can't get the annotations if we only have the MethodDeclarationContext. We need to visit the whole tree to find the corresponding ClassBodyDeclarationContext.

Now I am not familiar with listeners. From what I understand (and that's not a lot) you should use them if you need to work at parsing time. I'd rather just visit the tree generated by the parser. ANTLR should create a visitor for you  named `<your grammar name>ParserBaseVisitor`. All you have to do is extend this class and override the visit method for nodes of interest.

- Visit a ClassBodyDeclarationContext. To do so you must override the `visitClassBodyDeclaration(ClassBodyDeclarationContext ctx)`.
- Check that it is a method with `ctx.memberDeclaration().methodDeclaration()`. It should be null if it is not a method declaration. Else it should be a MethodDeclarationContext.
- If it is not, you might want to visit the child node (in case it is a class declaration). Call super if you extend the ParserBaseVisitor generated by antlr, since it is exactly what it does.
- If it is a method, retrieve the list of annotations an do whatever you want with it :-)

You should be able to retrieve the annotations like this:

```
Set<AnnotationContext> annotations = new HashSet<AnnotationContext>();
for(ClassOrInterfaceModifier modifier: ctx.modifier()) {
    if (modifier.classOrInterfaceModifier().annotation()) {
        annotations.add(modifier.classOrInterfaceModifier().annotation());
    }
}
```